# Strip "$" from csv file

Tags: php, csv

I have a php page that takes in a csv file and uploads it to my database. The issue I am having is that some of the fields have a '$' which i do not need. Is there a way to remove the $ from only some of the fields?

Data structure

```
COLL_ID   COCC_ID   AGEDTOTAL    PAYMENTTOTAL    
5074      11110     $7.50        ($7.50)
```

my Query

```
$deleterecords = "TRUNCATE TABLE mytable"; //empty the table of its     current records
mysql_query($deleterecords);

//Upload File
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $i=0;
    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])) {
    echo "<h1>" . "File ". $_FILES['filename']['name'] ." uploaded successfully." . "</h1>";
    echo "<h2>Displaying contents:</h2>";
    readfile($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']);
}

//Import uploaded file to Database
$handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    if ($i>0){
    $import="INSERT into mytable(COLL_ID, COCC_ID, AGEDTOTAL, PAYMENTTOTAL) values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]')";

    mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
}
$i++;
}
```

Comment: Try using `strpos()` combined with `str_replace()` maybe ? You might need to read the contents of `$data` array into individual variables before inserting into the database.

Comment: Besides the admonition to use MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements/bind variables rather than the old, deprecated MySQL interface.... can't you simply do a `str_replace(['$','', '', $field)` or a `ltrim($field, '$')` on those elements of the array?

Comment: I am using this instead ltrim('$data[2]','$')      but getting the error: Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ltrim'

Comment: The MySQL LTRIM() function is not the same as the PHP ltrim() function..... do it in PHP and DON'T PUT `$data[2]` IN SINGLE QUOTES....

Answer (score 0):

For the whole file

```
$string = preg_replace(
    '/((:?.*?\,){2}.*?)\$/',
    '$1',
    $string
);
```

2 is a ((Number of column that contains $ symbol) - 1)

or

```
$data[2] = str_replace('$', '', $data[2]);
```

Comment: The second approach is the one to chose! Place this statement before the `INSERT` statement. It would be even better (=faster, less obtrusive), if you collected all the data first and then executed a single `INSERT` command with multiple `(..)`s after the `VALUE` clause. You can construct this command by using `join()`.